# LSTM labeling all samples as the same class

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, deep-learning, keras, lstm

I'm trying to design an LSTM network using Keras to combine word embeddings and other features in a binary classification setting. My test set contains 250 samples per class.

When I run my model using only the word embedding layers (the "model" layer in the code), I get an average F1 of around 0.67. When I create a new branch with the other features of fixed size that I compute separately ("branch2") and merge these with the word embeddings using "concat", the predictions all revert to a single class (giving perfect recall for that class), and average F1 drops to 0.33.

Am I adding in the features and training/testing incorrectly?

```
def create_model(embedding_index, sequence_features, optimizer='rmsprop'):
    # Branch 1: word embeddings
    model = Sequential()
    embedding_layer = create_embedding_matrix(embedding_index, word_index)
    model.add(embedding_layer)
    model.add(Convolution1D(nb_filter=32, filter_length=3, border_mode='same', activation='tanh'))
    model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_length=2))
    model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(100)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))

    # Branch 2: other features
    branch2 = Sequential()
    dim = sequence_features.shape[1]
    branch2.add(Dense(15, input_dim=dim, init='normal', activation='tanh'))
    branch2.add(BatchNormalization())

    # Merging branches to create final model
    final_model = Sequential()
    final_model.add(Merge([model,branch2], mode='concat'))
    final_model.add(Dense(2, init='normal', activation='sigmoid'))
    final_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer,
           metrics=['accuracy','precision','recall','fbeta_score','fmeasure'])
    return final_model

def run(input_train, input_dev, input_test, text_col, label_col, resfile, embedding_index):
    # Processing text and features
    data_train, labels_train, data_test, labels_test = vectorize_text(input_train, input_test, text_col,label_col)
    x_train, y_train = data_train, labels_train
    x_test, y_test = data_test, labels_test
    seq_train = get_sequence_features(input_train).as_matrix()
    seq_test = get_sequence_features(input_test).as_matrix()

    # Generating model
    filepath = lstm_config.WEIGHTS_PATH
    checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_fmeasure', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')
    callbacks_list = [checkpoint]
    model = create_model(embedding_index, seq_train)
    model.fit([x_train, seq_train], y_train, validation_split=0.33, nb_epoch=3, batch_size=100, callbacks=callbacks_list, verbose=1)

    # Evaluating
    scores = model.evaluate([x_test, seq_test], y_test, verbose=1)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    preds = model.predict_classes([x_test, seq_test])
    preds = to_categorical(preds)
    print(metrics.f1_score(y_true=y_test, y_pred=preds, average="micro"))
    print(metrics.f1_score(y_true=y_test, y_pred=preds, average="macro"))
    print(metrics.classification_report(y_test, preds))
```

Output:

> Using Theano backend. Found 2999999 word vectors. 
>   Processing text dataset Found 7165 unique tokens. 
>   Shape of data tensor: (1996, 50)
>   Shape of label tensor: (1996, 2) 
>   1996 train 500 test 
>   Train on 1337 samples, validate on 659 samples
>
> Epoch 1/3 1300/1337
>   [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.6767 - acc:
>   0.6669 - precision: 0.5557 - recall: 0.6815 - fbeta_score: 0.6120 - fmeasure: 0.6120Epoch 00000: val_fmeasure im1337/1337
>   [==============================] - 10s - loss: 0.6772 - acc: 0.6672 -
>   precision: 0.5551 - recall: 0.6806 - fbeta_score: 0.6113 - fmeasure:
>   0.6113 - val_loss: 0.7442 - val_acc: 0 .0000e+00 - val_precision: 0.0000e+00 - val_recall: 0.0000e+00 - val_fbeta_score: 0.0000e+00 - val_fmeasure: 0.0000e+00
>
> Epoch 2/3 1300/1337
>   [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.6634 - acc:
>   0.7269 - precision: 0.5819 - recall: 0.7292 - fbeta_score: 0.6462 - fmeasure: 0.6462Epoch 00001: val_fmeasure di1337/1337
>   [==============================] - 9s - loss: 0.6634 - acc: 0.7263 -
>   precision: 0.5830 - recall: 0.7300 - fbeta_score: 0.6472 - fmeasure:
>   0.6472 - val_loss: 0.7616 - val_acc: 0. 0000e+00 - val_precision: 0.0000e+00 - val_recall: 0.0000e+00 - val_fbeta_score: 0.0000e+00 - val_fmeasure: 0.0000e+00
>
> Epoch 3/3 1300/1337
>   [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.6542 - acc:
>   0.7354 - precision: 0.5879 - recall: 0.7308 - fbeta_score: 0.6508 - fmeasure: 0.6508Epoch 00002: val_fmeasure di1337/1337
>   [==============================] - 8s - loss: 0.6545 - acc: 0.7337 -
>   precision: 0.5866 - recall: 0.7307 - fbeta_score: 0.6500 - fmeasure:
>   0.6500 - val_loss: 0.7801 - val_acc: 0. 0000e+00 - val_precision: 0.0000e+00 - val_recall: 0.0000e+00 - val_fbeta_score: 0.0000e+00 - val_fmeasure: 0.0000e+00 500/500 [==============================] - 0s
>   500/500 [==============================] - 1s
>   0.5 /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py:1074:
>
> UndefinedMetricWarning: F-score is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in
>   labels with no predicted samples.   'precision', 'predicted', average,
>   warn_for)
>   0.333333333333 /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py:1074:
>
> UndefinedMetricWarning: Precision and F-score are ill-defined and
>   being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples.
>
> ```
>          precision    recall  f1-score   support
>
>       0       0.00      0.00      0.00       250
>       1       0.50      1.00      0.67       250
> avg / total       0.25      0.50      0.33       500
> ```